# using cloc to count lines of codes in sub folders

Tags: lines-of-code, cloc

My Operating System is Windows. I have a main folder that contains projects within each sub folders. I want to report on each folder with foldername.txt. Then later I can sum them up with --sum-reports option. I looked at their options can't find a way to do it. Maybe I missed it.

Here is their [GitHub](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc) and description.

I have tried:

```
cloc-1.64.exe \\servername\mainfolder\ --report_file=everything
```

This only gives me one file listed by languages in all sub folders.

I also tried

```
cloc-1.64.exe \\servername\mainfolder\ --report_file=.\*.txt
```

cloc obviously doesn't like it.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
cloc YOURFOLDERNAME
```

and only that

Comment: Well, yes, but there is a hard limit, over this limit, `cloc` crashes, we have to loop on subdirectories.